# Evaluation and optimization in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

I am reading the [article](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/cacm12.pdf) "A few useful things to know about machine learning" by P. Domingos. Now, I am confused about two of the three components of learning, i.e., the evaluation and optimization. From the article, the evaluation function is the one used to distinguish good classifiers from bad ones, while the optimization is the method to search among all the classifiers for the highest-scoring one. So, they are kind of similar, right? Am I misunderstanding something here? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Is [this](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/cacm12.pdf) the article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluation is a score/metric that tells us how we are doing. For example, if we are trying to predict a number across a test set of size $n$, we can compute Mean Absolute Error = $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|observed_i - predicted_i|$ or we can compute Root Mean Squared Error = $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(observed_i - predicted_i)^2}$

Optimization refers to the representation and how we can choose different ways to optimize it. For example, we can try to simply try *every* possible hypothesis in our hypothesis space. Or we can use a more intelligent method to try the most promising hypothesis only. And as we are optimizing, we use our evaluation function to know if this particular hypotheses is better than another.

Comment: So the evaluation is the standard to use to see which hypothesis is better and the optimization is the process to choose among all different hypothesis. Right? In your answer, the mean absolute error or the root mean squared error is some examples of representation, right?

Comment: @JosephStone Yes to the first half of the statement. However, the mean absolute error and root mean squared error are examples of the evaluation function. Examples of the representation are the familiar algorithms such as Decision Trees and Neural Networks. Sorry for the confusion. I've updated the answer slightly

Comment: Also, as both evaluation and optimisation require some truth (i.e. true decision for some objects), they musn't ever use the same information, because it will make evaluation result biased and may hide overfitting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very clean answer.

Optimization consists of minimizing or maximizing an objective function with respect to one or more variables (a.k.a. parameters, a.k.a. arguments), possibly subject to constraints on those variables.

Viewed in this framework, "evaluation" means evaluating the objective function at a particular combination of variable values.  The optimizer has to evaluate the objective function (and possibly its gradient and maybe Hessian) at various values of the variables in order to carry out the optimization.